# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module A contains package B, module B exports package B to A

Tags: java, java-11, java-module, jcuda

I'm migrating my app from **Java 1.8** to **Java 11**, got the following error on one of my external jar at runtime.

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module image.viewer contains
>   package jcuda, module jcuda exports package jcuda to image.viewer

Here is my **Module.info** class

```
module image.viewer {

exports com.viewer;
exports com.viewer.backup;
exports com.viewer.backup.analyse;
exports com.viewer.compare;
exports com.viewer.controls;
exports com.viewer.database;
exports com.viewer.discovery;
exports com.viewer.events;
exports com.viewer.exif;
exports com.viewer.exportWorker;
exports com.viewer.external;
exports com.viewer.faceidentification;
exports com.viewer.gpuworker;
exports com.viewer.importers;
exports com.viewer.keypoints;
exports com.viewer.location;
exports com.viewer.model;
exports com.viewer.panes;
exports com.viewer.pool;
exports com.viewer.referenceDatabase;
exports com.viewer.registration;
exports com.viewer.renderers;
exports com.viewer.report;
exports com.viewer.search;
exports com.viewer.search.imfilters;
exports com.viewer.statistics;
exports com.viewer.surf;
exports com.viewer.tags;
exports com.viewer.thumbnail;
exports com.viewer.thumbnails;
exports com.viewer.util;
exports com.viewer.worker;
exports com.viewer.xmlWorker;

requires commons.dbcp;
requires ehcache;
requires eventbus;
requires transitive java.desktop;
requires java.sql;
requires java.activation;
requires java.xml;
requires java.xml.bind;
requires jna;
requires logback.classic;
requires logback.core;
requires lucene.core;
requires miglayout.swing;
requires slf4j.api;
requires snakeyaml;
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
requires commons.io;
requires commons.lang3;
requires jdk.unsupported;
requires jgoodies.forms;
requires commons.collections4;
requires java.prefs;
requires jfreechart;
requires synthetica.base;
requires synthetica.theme.aluoxide;
requires synthetica.theme.blackeye;
requires synthetica.theme.dark;
requires synthetica.theme.plain;
requires WMI4Java;
requires jdk.security.auth;
requires commons.cli;
requires synthetica.addons.swingx;
requires synthetica.addons.base;
requires exiftool.lib;
requires javacsv;
requires poi;
requires poi.ooxml;
requires poi.scratchpad;
requires xmlbeans;
requires itextpdf;
requires mapsforge.core;
requires mapsforge.map;
requires mapsforge.map.awt;
requires mapsforge.map.reader;
requires opencv;
requires image.group.mk5;
requires image.face.age;
requires image.object;
requires image.zoning;
requires roi.detector;
requires rot.profile.age;
requires zt.zip;
requires webp.io;
requires opencsv;
requires psd.analizer;
requires xmlworker;
requires java.management;
requires jdk.management;
requires batik.dom;
requires batik.transcoder;
requires jackson.annotations;
requires org.glassfish.java.json;
requires gson;
requires OOXML;
requires image.jcuda;

opens com.viewer.model to snakeyaml, java.xml.bin;

}
```

Comment: Based on *`module jcuda exports package jcuda to image.viewer`*, is there another module `jcuda` in your modulepath?

Comment: There are many jars in my modular path, JCuda is not repeating, I check it man times, I think some other jar might  have JCuda? I have check Maven Dependency Hierarchy and search JCuda but didn't found any.